Импорт модулей из корневой папки во вложенных папках Python3
имеется такая структура
project
       |- configuration.py #содержит class Config с настройками
       |- folder1
                |-module1.py
                |-module2.py
       |- folder2
                |-module3

в module3 пишу такую конструкцию
from configuration import config # Экземпляр класса Config

И получаю ошибку
В терминале
.venv/ # python.exe .\folder2\module3.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\project\folder2\module3.py", line 6, in <module>
    from configuration import config
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'configuration'

В VSCode такая же проблема, но в PyCharm всё работает.
Я так понимаю импортировать надо указывая пути. Но как сделать так, что бы можно было импортировать от корня проекта без дополнительных манипуляций с путями.

from project.configuration import config как вариант ‍♀️

Скрипт, который собирает весь код в один проект и далее производит компилированный исполняемый .pyc, пишется за 15 минут. При этом процесс сборки всех .py в один полностью контролируемый. Вторая причина проблем - использование from.  Рекомендую (именно рекомендую) избавиться от этой привычки и как можно скорее. Сборка единого .py, кстати, снимает и необходимость писанины всех этих ошибочных импортов. Есть вещи в жизни, которые надо делать не по глупым книжкам, а лично. Как минимум, детей и сборку скриптов. И тогда жизнь в Питоне становится скучной и предсказуемой.

Скрипт это хорошо, но лично для меня это пока далеко. Я пока использую не большие скрипты для автоматизации и учусь потихоньку.
